# 2D XArray cfgrib engine indexing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-xarray, grib

I'm wanting to extract data from grib2 files within a window of lat/long.

```
def get_data(temp_filename):
    ds = xr.open_dataset(temp_filename, engine="cfgrib")
    ds = ds[{'latitude': ds.latitude > 1, 'longitude': ds.longitude > -100}]
    radar_values = ds.to_array()
    print(radar_values)
```

Gives

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error is related to doing 2D indexing with xarray.

```
d = ds[{'latitude': ds.latitude > 1, 'longitude': ds.longitude > -100}]
```

should be done with the where() method

```
ds=ds.where(ds.latitude > 1)
ds=ds.where(ds.longitude > -100)
```

or by extracting the underlying array with numpy and doing appropriate indexing.

See http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html